# Error While Inserting in table which have column store index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi All can Anybody tell me why this is error is coming here is the stored proc

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.procedures WHERE NAME = 'InsertCategory')
BEGIN
DROP PROC InsertCategory
END

 GO
 Create proc dbo.InsertCategory
  @category nvarchar

   As 
   Begin

Declare @rs Int
Set @rs = 0

If(@category is not null)
BEGIN
    Alter Index Category_Clus On Categories Disable
        Set @rs =1
END
IF(@rs = 1)
BEGIN
    Insert Into Categories (
        Category)
    Values (
        @category)      
END

Alter Index Category_Clus on Categories Rebuild

 End
```

Error Which is coming is

```
Msg 35330, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertCategory, Line 18
 INSERT statement failed because data cannot be updated in a table with a 
   columnstore index. Consider disabling the columnstore index before 
    issuing the INSERT statement, then rebuilding the columnstore index 
     after INSERT is complete.
```

I am Executing the stored proc as

```
Exec InsertCategory 'D'
```

I am using non clustered column store index on Categories table

Comment: Pls pay attention to the tags! This question is for ms sql server, not for mysql!

Comment: 1) What version of SQL Server are you using? Insert the result of `SELECT @@VERSION` into your question. 2) Please show the definition of your columnstore index.

Comment: I am using sql server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like you have a non-clustered columnstore index on the table and are using SQL Server 2014 or earlier. Tables with columstore indexes are updatable in later versions.

You won't be able to disable and rebuild the index in the same proc as the `INSERT` statement unless you execute the `INSERT` using dynamic SQL. This is because the proc is compiled with the index in place and inserts are not allowed on tables with a columnstore index in earlier versions of SQL Server. For example:

```
CREATE proc dbo.InsertCategory
  @category nvarchar
AS

DECLARE @rs int;
SET @rs = 0

IF @category IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER INDEX Category_Clus ON Categories DISABLE;
    SET @rs =1;
END
IF @rs = 1
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT Into dbo.Categories (Category) Values (@category)'
    , N'@category nvarchar(1)'
    , @category = @category;
END;

ALTER INDEX Category_Clus ON Categories REBUILD;
GO
```

Disabling and rebuilding indexes is not something that should be done routinely for singleton inserts for performance and concurrency reasons.  Also, I suggest you specify an explicit length for the nvarchar parameter since the default length is 1.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like discussion of similar problem in below article. There is a work around in below article. Please refer below article -
    https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226467/How-to-update-a-table-with-a-columnstore-index